# why are the results of the two queries different

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

**the first query:**

```
  SELECT  u.id , prop1.id   
   FROM    ( SELECT    '9fbc6e9b59504c08ac643752c1e2d033' AS id ,
                    '|6813dbbfec6241a19b8d2316d2cb2a65,1|' AS customprop
          UNION
          SELECT    'f2271c45682f45fc84527c4afff0ab16' AS id ,
                    '|6813dbbfec6241a19b8d2316d2cb2a65,2|' AS customprop
        ) u
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY a.Id ) id ,
                            A.Id propId ,
                            B.NAME
                     FROM   ( SELECT    '6813dbbfec6241a19b8d2316d2cb2a65' AS id ,
                                        CONVERT(XML, '<v>1,职业资格1</v><v>2,职业资格2</v>') AS value
                            ) A
                            OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    Name = N.v.value('.',
                                                              'nvarchar(Max)')
                                          FROM      A.[VALUE].nodes('/v') N ( v )
                                        ) B
                   ) prop1 ON CHARINDEX('|' + prop1.propid + ','
                                        + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), prop1.id)
                                        + '|', u.customprop) > 0
GROUP BY u.id ,
        prop1.id
```

**the second query:**

```
SELECT  u.id ,prop1.id, count(*)
    FROM    ( SELECT    '9fbc6e9b59504c08ac643752c1e2d033' AS id ,
                        '|6813dbbfec6241a19b8d2316d2cb2a65,1|' AS customprop
              UNION
              SELECT    'f2271c45682f45fc84527c4afff0ab16' AS id ,
                        '|6813dbbfec6241a19b8d2316d2cb2a65,2|' AS customprop
            ) u
            INNER JOIN ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY a.Id ) id ,
                                A.Id propId ,
                                B.NAME
                         FROM   ( SELECT    '6813dbbfec6241a19b8d2316d2cb2a65' AS id ,
                                            CONVERT(XML, '<v>1,职业资格1</v><v>2,职业资格2</v>') AS value
                                ) A
                                OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    Name = N.v.value('.',
                                                                  'nvarchar(Max)')
                                              FROM      A.[VALUE].nodes('/v') N ( v )
                                            ) B
                       ) prop1 ON CHARINDEX('|' + prop1.propid + ','
                                            + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), prop1.id)
                                            + '|', u.customprop) > 0
    GROUP BY u.id ,
            prop1.id
```

sql can be executed on sqlserver 2005 directly.
the first query can produce one item and the second query produce two items.
I think that the two queries should both produce two items.
I have thouht for three days and I really want to konw why. 
I'm a Chinese and my English is poor.I hope you can  understand my description

Comment: You may wish to make it easier if you could format the code and explain what you are wanting to do, or at least what is happening.  I can only see one query here.

Comment: To find out your problem i suggest you to break your query apart and run it separetelly, inside to outside. Run the part of the query that is subquery A and B. Then run just your union from U subquery. analyse the data from theese two. Execute the CHARINDEX part 'by hand' on the A and B query see what returns. Also, it will be great if you can create a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Tried it on my machine and got the same results from both queries.

Comment: I have change the query,please try it again!

Comment: I get the same results as the OP on my SQL Servers also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tough question, but the problem is with this line:

```
INNER JOIN ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY a.Id ) id ,
```

The `ORDER BY` is ambiguous and consequently, if it is executed multiple times (which it can be because of the `INNER JOIN` it is contained in), it may not always return the same ordering/assignment.  This can cause a latter join condition to only match on one record instead of two, which is what happens in the query plan being used for the version without the `count(*)` column.

To fix this, you just need to add something to make the ordering assignment unique, like this:

```
INNER JOIN ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY a.Id, B.Name ASC ) id ,
```

Try it like this, it should work.

Comment: please see the third answer that I post.It is also a question that I want to ask you again.thank you !

Comment: @一无所有 First, do not post additions to your questions as an answer, just edit your original question and add it to the end.  Secondly, your third query works because because the optimizer decided to do the branch with the `ROW_NUMBER` first, instead of second, and then to save the output in a `Table Spool/(Lazy Spool)` to look up later.  This is essentially the same as a temp table and that it only executes the `ROW_NUMBER` scan once, then saves it, and looks it up later on.  This has the side-effect of insuring that the IDs stay the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient guide, your answer is very useful to me, and I want to tell you the website movingsql.com has a mistake, thank you again for you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the ORDER BY clause of the ROW_NUMBER - since the a.ID is not unique the outcome is unpredictable. Make that unique and your problem will go away - you can use something like

```
...SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY newid() ) id...
```